# Find all possible combinations from 4 input numbers which can add up to 24

Tags: algorithm

Actually, this question can be generalized as below:

> Find all possible combinations from a given set of elements, which meets
>   a certain criteria.

So, any good algorithms?

Comment: Could very well be wrong on this, but I believe that the general form of your problem is NP complete (in other words, there's not going to be a particularly pretty answer).

Comment: I think it is NP-Complete. Have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for people to stop citing NP-completeness?  The brute-force approach is perfectly tractable here, as see in the leading answer.  Besides, in 99% of cases, the OP is looking for a GOOD algorithm.  Not an optimal algorithm.

Comment: is this set possible(0,0,0,24)?

Comment: @amin k - depends on how you define your answer parameters.  I you allow 0, 1, 2, 3, to be zeros or not.

Answer (score 9):

There are only 16 possibilities (and one of those is to add together "none of them", which ain't gonna give you 24), so the old-fashioned "brute force" algorithm looks pretty good to me:

```
for (unsigned int choice = 1; choice < 16; ++choice) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (choice & 1) sum += elements[0];
    if (choice & 2) sum += elements[1];
    if (choice & 4) sum += elements[2];
    if (choice & 8) sum += elements[3];
    if (sum == 24) {
        // we have a winner
    }
}
```

In the completely general form of your problem, the only way to tell whether a combination meets "certain criteria" is to evaluate those criteria for every single combination. Given more information about the criteria, maybe you could work out some ways to avoid testing every combination and build an algorithm accordingly, but not without those details. So again, brute force is king.

Comment: how did you determine there are only 16 possibilities? I would assume the number of possibilities is dependent on both the amount of input numbers and the sum.

Comment: @Pat: the title of this question is, "Find all possilbe combinations from 4 input numbers...". The thing is, if there are too many inputs for my trick above to work (using an integer type as a bitfield), then there are too many inputs to brute force it at all. And since the general version of the question is *so* general there is no algorithm other than brute force. Successively incrementing an integer is certainly the fastest way to iterate across a representation of each member of the power set -- whether it's the most useful representation depends on things that have been generalized away.

Answer (score 2):

There are two interesting explanations about the sum problem, both in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html).

In the case of the first question you asked, the first answer is good for a limited number of elements. You should realize that the reason Mr. Jessop used 16 as the boundary for his loop is because this is 2^4, where 4 is the number of elements in your set. If you had 100 elements, the loop limit would become 2^100 and your algorithm would literally take forever to finish.

In the case of a bounded sum, you should consider a depth first search, because when the sum of elements exceeds the sum you are looking for, you can prune your branch and backtrack.

In the case of the generic question, finding the subset of elements that satisfy certain criteria, this is known as the Knapsack problem, which is known to be NP-Complete. Given that, there is no algorithm that will solve it in less than exponential time.

Nevertheless, there are several heuristics that bring good results to the table, including (but not limited to) genetic algorithms (one I personally like, for I wrote a book on them) and dynamic programming. A simple search in Google will show many scientific papers that describe different solutions for this problem.

Comment: Agreed, if it was 100 rather than 4 then I'd have to give a different answer. I disagree that the questioner's general problem is the knapsack problem -- "satisfies certain criteria" is *far* more general than "maximises total value subject to a limit on total weight". Basically, the restricted problem here is too small, and the general problem too general, to generate any interesting technique. Of course there are any number of problems between the two, that are interesting :-)

Comment: "when the sum of elements exceeds the sum you are looking for, you can prune" -- if the elements are all non-negative. Otherwise you can still prune some branches, but not that readily.

Comment: I agree with the pruning assertion. Nevertheless, the knapsack problem is not restricted to a limit on the total weight - that is the token teaching problem. You can use any function of the bits you may need!

Answer (score 1):

> Find all possible combinations from a given set of elements, which
>   meets a certain criteria

If i understood you right, this code will helpful for you:

```
    >>> from itertools import combinations as combi    
    >>> combi.__doc__
'combinations(iterable, r) --> combinations object\n\nReturn successive r-length
 combinations of elements in the iterable.\n\ncombinations(range(4), 3) --> (0,1
,2), (0,1,3), (0,2,3), (1,2,3)'
    >>> set = range(4)
    >>> set
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
    >>> criteria = range(3)
    >>> criteria
    [0, 1, 2]
    >>> for tuple in list(combi(set, len(criteria))):
    ...     if cmp(list(tuple), criteria) == 0:
    ...             print 'criteria exists in tuple: ', tuple
    ...
    criteria exists in tuple:  (0, 1, 2)

    >>> list(combi(set, len(criteria)))
    [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally for a problem as this you have to try all posebilities, the thing you should do have the code abort the building of combiantion if you know it will not satesfie the  criteria (if you criteria is that you do not have more then two blue balls, then you have to abort calculation that has more then two). [Backtracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

```
def perm(set,permutation): 
    if lenght(set) == lenght(permutation):
       print permutation
    else:
        for element in set:
           if permutation.add(element) == criteria:
               perm(sett,permutation)
           else:
                permutation.pop()  //remove the element added in the if
```

Answer (score 0):

The set of input numbers matters, as you can tell as soon as you allow e.g. negative numbers, imaginary numbers, rational numbers etc in your start set. You could also restrict to e.g. all even numbers, all odd number inputs etc.

That means that it's hard to build something deductive. You need brute force, a.k.a. try every combination etc.

In this particular problem you could build an algoritm that recurses - e.g. find every combination of 3 Int ( 1,22) that add up to 23, then add 1, every combination that add to 22 and add 2 etc. Which can again be broken into every combination of 2 that add up to 21 etc. You need to decide if you can count same number twice.

Once you have that you have a recursive function to call -

```
combinations( 24 , 4 ) = combinations( 23, 3 ) + combinations( 22, 3 ) + ... combinations( 4, 3 );
combinations( 23 , 3 ) = combinations( 22, 2 ) + ... combinations( 3, 2 );
```

etc

This works well except you have to be careful around repeating numbers in the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int[][] work()
    {
        const int target = 24;
        List<int[]> combos = new List<int[]>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
                    for (int z = 0; z < 9; z++)
                    {
                        int res = x + y + z + i;
                        if (res == target)
                        {
                            combos.Add(new int[] { x, y, z, i });
                        }
                    }
        return combos.ToArray();
    }
```

It works instantly, but there probably are better methods rather than 'guess and check'. All I am doing is looping through every possibility, adding them all together, and seeing if it comes out to the target value.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, what you are asking for is called "Permutations" or the number (N) of possible ways to arrange (X) numbers taken from a set of (Y) numbers.

```
N = Y! / (Y - X)!
```

I don't know if this will help, but this is a solution I came up with for an assignment on permutations.

You have an input of : 123 (string) using the substr functions

1) put each number of the input into an array

```
array[N1,N2,N3,...]
```

2)Create a swap function

```
function swap(Number A, Number B)
{
   temp = Number B 
   Number B = Number A   
   Number A = temp   
}
```

3)This algorithm uses the swap function to move the numbers around until all permutations are done.

```
original_string= '123'    
temp_string=''

While( temp_string != original_string)
{
   swap(array element[i], array element[i+1])

   if (i == 1)
       i == 0

   temp_string = array.toString
   i++
}
```

Hopefully you can follow my pseudo code, but this works at least for 3 digit permutations

Answer (score 0):

(n X n )
built up a square matrix of nxn

and print all together its corresponding crossed values

e.g.

1   2   3   4

1 11  12  13  14

2 ..  ..  ..  ..

3 ..

4 ..          ..